# Linux regex - Using an OR operator at beginning of line

Tags: regex, linux, shell

I have a csv file which I need to pull the first column out of. I would like to take the header (comprised of letters) and the data which is comprised only of numbers.

Sample input:

```
"HEADER1","HEADER2"
"1234567","TEXT"
"3456789","TEXT2"
```

As both are encapsulated within double quotes my output should be:

```
"HEADER"
"1234567"
"3456789"
```

I am currently using the following regex, which is only giving me the data and not the header. I thought the 'OR' operator in the middle would include any text as well as numbers encapsulated by double quotes. Any idea why this isn't giving me my header?

```
grep -o "^\"[0-9]\+\"\|^\"[A-Z]\+\"\"" test.csv > test2.csv
```

Cheers

Comment: did you try `grep -o "^\"[0-9A-Z]\+\"" test.csv` ?

Comment: @leu, there's a difference between `[0-9]\+\|[A-Z]\+` and `[0-9A-Z]\+`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have closed your quotation for `"[A-Z]\+"` twice:

```
grep -o "^\"[0-9]\+\"\|^\"[A-Z]\+\"\"" test.csv > test2.csv
                                   ^^
```

Remove that and all is well. To make it easier to understand, use single quotation:

```
grep -o '^"[0-9]\+"\|^"[A-Z]\+"' test.csv > test2.csv
```

Comment: Is there something wrong with the regex? I'd appreciate comments on the downvote so I can learn too.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex contains too many *\"* at the end.
Use:

```
grep -o "^\"[0-9]\+\"\|^\"[A-Z]\+\"" test.csv > test2.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk:

```
awk -F, '$1 ~ /"[0-9]+|[a-zA-Z]+"/ {print $1}' file
```